# Checking to see if you can call methods from an api before calling it

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have the following code:

```
var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
var runtimeMethods = view.GetType().GetRuntimeMethods();
if (!view.IsFullScreen)
{
    var tryEnterFullScreenMode = runtimeMethods.FirstOrDefault(
        x => x.Name == "TryEnterFullScreenMode");
    tryEnterFullScreenMode?.Invoke(view, null);
}
```

What this does is cause my application to become fullscreen however if I'm on a windows 8.1 pc I can't call these methods. How can I first check to see if this functionality is available before calling the methods. Will I use #if...#endif?
Basically I would like to only use this code when the app is running on a machine that has access to it(Windows 10 operating system).

Answer (score 0):

Desktop development doesn't suffer from fragmentation experienced by web development, therefore there is no *feature support* query, rather *library support/os version*. Nor that I know, at least.

What usually done is

1)  *Dynamic* loading of assemblies, based on the OS family version you are running on.  For that you need some common interface wrapper, that holds inside, under the hood, all "real" API calls.

2) Have distinct version for every *different* OS family. You need to support 2 code bases. Event though, the code that *actually* different may be moved to separate assembly, so you have only small set of assemblies that are different between different families of OSes. Good for patching, as only relatively small amount of data has to be moved to the client. Still common interface is required here.

So the basic question you have to find answer is: not how to handle diversity, but rather, what you should do once you find that you need to do something different from expected. From that you can understand most reliable way you are going to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use essentially that code on a Windows 8.1 system. On Windows 10 tryEnterFullScreenMode will be set. On Windows 8.1 it will be null. Invoke the method only if it is set:

```
var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
TypeInfo t = typeof(ApplicationView).GetTypeInfo();
var tryEnterFullScreenMode = t.GetDeclaredMethod("TryEnterFullScreenMode");
if (tryEnterFullScreenMode != null)
{
    tryEnterFullScreenMode.Invoke(view, null);
}
```

Windows 10 introduces proper feature support so you don't to fall back on reflection. You can check if a Contract or API exists with   [Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.metadata.apiinformation.aspx). This allows checking for features that are device specific or version specific and then easily calling them with normal syntax (rather than reflection syntax) if they are present. The check can be based on contract, type, or individual method, property, or event:

```
// Useless example since TryEnterFullScreenMode is in the UniversalApiContract
// and so guaranteed to be there in all Windows 10 apps
bool isEnterFullScreenPresent = Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsMethodPresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView", "TryEnterFullScreenMode");

if (isEnterFullScreenPresent)
{
    ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();
}
```

For more on API Contracts and feature detection see the [Guide to Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#writing_code) on MSDN.